# Dynamic convertibility type trait

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

Is it possible to enumerate a list of types to which a type can be converted to? Or would this require a technique similar to static reflection?

```
struct a {
    operator int() const
    { return i; }

    explicit operator float() const
    { return f; }

    int i;
    float f;
};

// enumerated type list for type 'a': tuple<int, float>
```

One of the things I would like to be able to do—which is related to this but with a somewhat narrower scope—is to check if a type is convertible to, let's say, an integral type, without having to explicitly list them.

The only way I'm able to do this now, is to create a tuple-like type-list of all those integer types, throw it in `std::is_convertible` and expand them within a `std::conjunction`. But I would really prefer to use a way which doesn't require me write out all the types of a specific type class. I'm specifically looking for a solution that is compatible with `C++17` but if that is not possible or is simply too cumbersome, a `C++20` solution is acceptable too.

---

The first part of my question seems to be well answered by Igor Tandetnik and Barry. Enumerating all of the types to which a type can be converted to would be undesirable for the reasons they have laid out. Enumerating the non-templated user-defined converion operators of a type could be useful but that would require someting like static reflection, which isn't possible for the time being.

Regarding the second part of my question, it seems that there are some nuances involved with type conversions between arithmetic types. Since they are all convertible to each other, finding the type trait that fits my needs maybe requires a different approach. I've decided to list a couple examples to better describe the requirements of this type trait.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct a {
    operator int() const
    { return i; }

    explicit operator float() const
    { return f; }

    int i;
    float f;
};

// this succeeds, but instead of explicitly writing out 'int' I would like to
// express my intent and write someting as 'any_integral_type' (note: I
// understand that integral types might be too narrow to properly detect,
// so 'any_arithmetic_type' could be acceptable too) and I would
// like to do so without listing all of the integral types by hand
static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<a, int>);

struct b {
    int i;
    float f;
};

// the difference between type 'a' and type 'b' seems rather obvious and
// I would like to have a type trait that can express that. how to write
// 'assert that b cannot be converted to any type that belongs to the
// std::integral_types' without explicitly writing 'int'?
static_assert(not std::is_convertible_v<b, int>);

// another idea is to use the unary addition operator to force the implicit
// conversion, this way we don't have to be upfront about which type to convert
// to, but this runs into ambiguity issues when there is more than one viable
// conversion operator (e.g.: when operator float isn't marked explicit)
static_assert(std::is_integral_v<decltype(+std::declval<a>())>);
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/v6McWhrYh).

Comment: I doubt it. First, this list could be infinite; `template <typename T> operator T() { return T{}; }` Second, I'm pretty sure I can encode an arbitrary computable function into `is_convertible` relationship (e.g. my class is convertible to `char****...` (a star repeated `n` times) iff `n` is prime). which would turn such enumeration into a halting problem. Recall that C++ template metaprogramming is Turing-complete.

Comment: What good is it to ask if a type is convertible to *some* integral type? You don't ask a type to convert to something; your code will ask to convert it to a specific thing. When the time comes that you know the specific thing you want to convert it to, then you can ask if it is convertible to that thing.

Comment: @NicolBolas The idea is to be able to constrain some templated function or class to e.g. integral types in order to do some integral specific things depending on the input. It is possible to do this with `concepts`/`std::enable_if` and the `std::is_integral` type trait. However, this becomes trickier when attempting to extend the constraint to types that can act like integral types as well.

Comment: @303: There is no way to write code that performs a conversion to an integral type. There is a way to write code that performs a conversion to a type `T` which itself is an integral type. But the code in question always goes to a *specific* type `T`. That is, `is_integral auto x = expr;` will only compile if `expr` is an integral type, not if it is convertible to one. So at some point, you have a type `T` that you want to convert the object to. So that's what you ask if it is convertible to.

Comment: @303: That is, constraints exist to protect a piece of code that has a specific need. Convertibility to `is_integral` is not a specific need, because you cannot write code that converts the type to *some* integral type. You can only write code that converts to a specific type.

Comment: @303: Can you give an example of types that can act like integral types? There could be a solution to constrain to those.

Comment: @Sebastian I'm specifically looking for any type that adheres to the [`std::is_integral`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral`) type trait. But considering the remarks of Igor Tandetnik, Nicol Bolas, and Barry, I might be looking for a type trait that fundamentally requires a different approach. I'll add some examples that will hopefully clarify the requirements.

Comment: Is your aim to be able to write a `static_assert` or do you also want to be able to use it as a concept or constraint for template arguments, e.g. to define a function template or class template only for convertible types?

Comment: @Sebastian Preferably something that nicely fits inside the condition of a `std::enable_if` but a type trait that (in)directly inherits from `std::true_type`/`std::false_type` is fine too.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to enumerate a list of types to which a type can be converted to?

No. Such a list of types is infinite. For instance, your `a` is convertible to `int` and `float`, yes. But also `short` and `double` and `char` and so forth, as far as obvious things go.

But then also `std::any` because it's copyable. And `std::optional<a>`. And `std::variant<a>`. And then `std::variant<a, T>` for all types `T` that are not `a` or `a const` (even if `a` is convertible to `T`, like `int`). Which is an obviously infinite list, even by itself. And then `std::variant<a, T1, T2>`, etc.

So not only is such a list of types infinite, but it's uncountably infinite.

> Or would this require a technique similar to static reflection?

I suspect what you actually are asking for is a very narrow question: Given a type `T`, what are all of its conversion functions? For those conversion functions that are not functinon templates (you can't really enumerate `template <typename T> operator T() const;` for instance), then yes -- static reflection would let you enumerate that list.

But note that that list is just going to be the list of types that `T` has conversion functions into. That list is *not* the list of types that `T` is convertible to. Just a subset thereof.

Comment: "list of types ... is uncountably infinite" I don't see how this can possibly be true. The set of all possible types is countable; if nothing else, they could be named by finite sequences of characters taken from a finite alphabet. In fact, the set of all possible C++ programs is countable.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sure, if you set a finite limit for the number of characters, then you will obviously end up with a finite set of anything. And maybe it's silly to consider what it even means to have an infinite program, but it's also besides the point.

Comment: Each program is of finite length. A set of all programs with length not exceeding some `N` is indeed finite. The set of all programs, however long, is countably infinite. Yes, I admit this is nitpicking not relevant to the main point; but being a geek, I couldn't let an incorrect claim pass. [Duty calls](https://xkcd.com/386/)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If you're capping programs at finite length, then the set of all programs is still finite, not infinite.

Comment: The set of integer sequences (or words) of finite (but unbounded) length is infinite but countably so.  The set of integer sequences that are themselves of infinite length is uncountably infinite.